# Execute a method to stop threads during Jetty Shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty

Hi have started few threads through
fixedThreadPool.

During Jetty shutdown I want to call a method where these threads are stopped.

Let me know how to do this ?

Comment: I want to get Jetty shutdown and call this method. But I am not sure how to get the shutdown hook ?

Comment: Are you using embedded jetty?

Comment: And why do you want to stop the threads?. If they are running under jetty, once Jetty shuts down all the running thread will be killed.

Comment: @Sirsendu, Yes I am using embedded jetty. These threads I am starting specifically to do some asynchronous work. I need them to be in the thread pool. But I need to stop them as they are not started by jetty. I need to stop them when the application goes down gracefully.

Comment: @Sirsendu, How to make threads to be killed when Jetty goes down ? Is there any configuration or something ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in the context of a webapp, then you can start and stop that sort of thing in a ServletContextListener.  If you are operating outside of that then you can create and register a Lifecycle object and add it to your server instance, then a doStop() method will be called on your object and let you gracefully end things.

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about abrupt termination of the background tasks being executed by the threads spawned by a [fixedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29), you can call the [shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) method to stop the threads.

If you do care about clean termination, use the [awaitTermination()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method instead.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. But where and to when to call is my problem. I need to call only when my application goes down gracefully. We are using embedded jetty.

Comment: Programmatic shutdown or when it receives Ctrl+C from the console?

Comment: Perhaps this [article](http://www.petervannes.nl/files/084d1067451c4f9a56f9b865984f803d-52.php) is close to what you are trying to achieve?